# NodeJS uploading images with Multer, getting "Error: unexpected field"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I'm getting "Error: Unexpected field" when trying to process and store some uploaded images via NgFileUpload. Here's my Angular code:

HTML:

```
<div ngf-drop="upload($files)" ngf-select="upload($files)" ng-model="files" 
  ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" 
  ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
  ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}" ngf-keep="'distinct'" 
  name="artistUpload" class="drop-box">

  Drop images here or click to upload
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
  $scope.$watch('files', function () {
      $scope.upload($scope.files);
  });

  $scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        console.log(files);
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/api/photos/upload/',
            arrayKey: '',
            data: {
                files: files
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0) {
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress =
                Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }
};
```

Express:

```
var multer  = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req);
    cb(null, '/private/img/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/api/photos/upload/', upload.array('photos', 6), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Files saved");
    console.log(req.files);
    next();
})
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917617/multer-not-accepting-files-in-array-format-gives-unexpected-filed-error) suggests that `arrayKey: ''` can solve the issue, but this hasn't worked for me at all. It's a pretty useless error from Multer! Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here's the error coming out of Node:

```
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (root/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (root/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (root/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
    at emitMany (events.js:108:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Busboy.emit (root/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (root/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at HeaderParser._finish (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at emitMany (events.js:108:13)
    at SBMH.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (root/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
    at SBMH.push (root/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (root/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)
    at emitMany (events.js:108:13)
```

Comment: the fields name are miss matching between client and server. check https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/301 it is expected to work that way https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/79e2c479f23d2128618aac3dd6b33a805fa84409/test/expected-files.js#L23

Comment: @mh-cbon Great, this fixed it. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Upload name and the fieldname in `<img>` is different. You need to match them both.
On server side keep both values same `upload.array('artistUpload')`